# Startup Disk Creator error on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, startup-disk-creator

I got this error message in Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu 18.10.

[image: utf-8 codec cant decode byte 0xbb in position 0: invalid start byte]

```
An unhandled exception occurred:
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The file you're using may be corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Startup Disk Creator tried to convert a byte-array (a group bytes which it assumes to be a utf-8-encoded string). This process was decoding according to utf-8 rules. When it tried this, it encountered a byte sequence which is not allowed in utf-8-encoded strings (the 0xbb at position 0).

See if you can find the source of the .iso image that you have selected in Startup Disk Creator. At the same place where you downloaded the .iso image there should be a checksum file (md5, sha1 or sha256 sums) that can be used to verify the integrity of the .iso image that you downloaded using the GtkHash application from the default Ubuntu repositories.

To install GtkHash in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gtkhash
```

If the .iso file passes the integrity check then there is some bug in Startup Disk Creator, so try making the Ubuntu installation USB using mkusb instead.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```